# Keyboard shortcut for texture paint brush strength?

Tags: interface, customization, texture-painting, shortcut

When texture painting the two most commonly adjusted settings are (in my experience) brush **Radius** and **Strength**. Radius already has shortcuts to decrease or increase: <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys respectively.

I want to configure a shortcut to similarly adjust the Strength.

[image]

From the console I can see that when <kbd>[</kbd> is pressed this happens:

```
bpy.ops.brush.scale_size(scalar=0.9)
```

And when <kbd>]</kbd> is pressed this happens:

```
bpy.ops.brush.scale_size(scalar=1.11111)
```

Here is what the key configuration for <kbd>[</kbd> looks like:

[image]

So I am hoping there is some kind of corresponding command for Strength, but nothing I've tried has worked.

For example: `brush.scale_strength` does not work.

**Is it possible to set keyboard shortcuts for the Strength slider?**

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't Shift+F work? Also there's F command for brush size; they are the same as [ and ] but no need to get to that part of keyboard

Comment: @MrZak Yes, of course! I had forgotten all about **F** and **Shift F**! (facepalm) Thank you! Still a bit curious if other sliders can be customized to be set up like Radius, but for all practical purposes the F shortcuts are just what I need. Cheers.

Comment: There's addon Sculpt/Paint Brush menus (likely shipped with Blender) which asigns to some keyboard shortcut and you can get to whole paint menu with it

Comment: @MrZak Thanks! I just tried it. “Sculpt/Paint Brush Menus” It's good for freeing up screen real estate while painting. I assigned its shortcut to my Wacom pen. Nice tip. :-)

Comment: EZ Paint (formerly Texture Paint Plus) also has popup controls on W/Shift-W/Ctrl-W etc and enables me to go full screen when painting. https://github.com/artistCDMJ/ez_paint/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for Strength, <kbd>F</kbd> for Radius, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for rotation of brush texture.

When using a brush texture in Stencil mode, <kbd>RMB</kbd> to move, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to scale, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to rotate the stencil image.

When using Stencil in Brush Mask, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to move, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to scale, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to rotate.

I use these all day, and prefer them to the typical  <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> usage in photoshop and other editors.