# Changing brush values while sculpting

Tags: sculpting

I don't know much about Blender at all, but I am using it lately to work on head morphs for Poser. 
I mostly work in the sculpting area but I am finding some difficulties changing the values of the brushes easily. 
With Poser and Photoshop there is a dial that lets me control things, like size of the brush. But in Blender I seem to only be able to type in the value manually. This can be a pain because I don't have a desk for my tablet so I have to put it on my keyboard, which means I have to keep moving my tablet. 
Is there something I'm missing here? Or can you only change the brush values by manually typing them in?

Comment: Move the cursor over the value you want to change, press Ctrl while scrolling on the mouse wheel to change the value. Or left click on the value and slide the mouse (or pen, if you are using a tablet). Also pressing [ and ] will increase or decrease the radius for the sculpt tool.

Comment: Similar answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100805/keyboard-shortcut-for-texture-paint-brush-strength